# In "The Sandman #1, Sleep of the Just" why didn't Morpheus try to communicate with his captors in any way?

Tags: vertigo-comics, the-sandman

When released, Morpheus complains about how torturous his captivity was, and how badly it messed up the mortal world.  However, he never mentions any of this when actually in captivity.  Why?  It seems like if his captors knew what was happening they would have behaved differently.

Comment: Yes, they would have demanded that he perform miracles for them

Comment: I believe it was clear in the voice-over that Morpheus believed (with some cause) that his captors more or less understood that his captivity was the reason for various problems, and they simply didn't care.

Comment: "*Burgess strips the unconscious Sandman of his pouch, helmet, ruby, and clothing, and places him naked in a glass cage surrounded by a mystic circle. When the prisoner awakens, Burgess demands immortality, power, and a pledge against revenge as the conditions for the Sandman s release; but **Dream refuses to even acknowledge Burgess’s existence. Instead, the Sandman maintains a stoic silence for the duration of his imprisonment in Burgess’s basement**... which lasts seventy-two years.* - Sandman Companion

Comment: Why he didn't call any of his siblings is a better question. Still general thing is a century is barely anything for Endless.

Comment: @Mithoron - Death takes him to task for not summoning her. It's not clear if he's able to actually have done so, but pride probably wouldn't have prevented him from doing so, had he had the wherewithal to do it.

Comment: @Mithoron - ***Neil Gaiman***: *...to my mind, Death knew about the Sandman being trapped as soon as it happened. Everyone in his family did. The reason the Endless didn't free him isn't because they weren't aware of the situation. but because they aren’t a superteam; rushing to the rescue isn’t what they’re about. The Endless stick to hoeing their own farms. As personifications of things, they're not causative. They're barely reactive.*  -Sandman Companion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Because of his pride

Please note, how proudful is Morpheus - he is the **King of Dreaming**, mortals spend one-third of their life in his realm, where he reigns, and now they dare to imprison him? He, who is almost as old as the universe will not lower himself to acknowledge the petty demands of this wannabe wizard. Once, when a woman displeased him, she sent her to Hell for eternity! Please also note how he behaves towards Lucienne when he finally returns to Dreaming - he is immediately aloof, expecting everyone to do as he says.

For the same reason he didn't ask for help from any of his siblings - he was too proud to admit to any of them, that he was in trouble - it would be a sign of weakness. <sup>1</sup>

The whole "Sandman" (both the graphic novel and the Netflix adaptation) shows the slow change in the way that Dream perceives humans (or actually all other beings) - not as just meaningless visitors in his realm, but as complex creatures worth his compassion - notice how his attitude towards the immortal Hob Gadling was changing over the years.

<sup>1 - The prequel story shows that Morpheus was imprisoned once before, but none of his siblings came to help him, even when he asked for it</sup>

Comment: ... addition to footnote.... and when he was "freed", it was because Destiny yanked him out to yell at him for leaving his crap laying around (which he hadn't; classic siblings)